# android - activity name in share button list

Tags: android

I added my app to the share list of the gallery app:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

But in the list the name that appears is the activity one not the app one

Answer (score 1):

> But in the list the name that appears is the activity one not the app one

Set activity's `android:name` to the same value you set for `<application>` tag in your Manifest.

BTW: there's no "app name" really. It's in fact label of activity with right intent filter for launcher to use.

Comment: I get a `is not asignable to` error. Changing the label works. The activity has no action bar, but I think changing the label changes the action bar title.